# Display D3 Network Graph Horizontally without folding

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, force-layout

I'm creating a Network graph which connects nodes with paths.

My requirements are simple - The Network graph should be either vertical or horizontal
without it folding.

So far, I created a graph that displays the chart in horizontal format.

However, the graph only displays in single line (without folding) if there are very limited set of nodes( i tried multiple trial-error of `forceManyBody().strength()` and `forceLink(links).distance()` to somehow get it working)

[image]

But for larger no. of nodes, the graph folds itself like this --

[image]

Some variation of `d3.forceManyBody().strength(-600)` gives me a single row but with reverse order of links , like this--

[image]

Here, 5050 circle should be first cirle but its coming at the end.

So, my questions are --

1. How to find `forceManyBody().strength()` and `forceLink(links).distance()` correctly based on nodes so I have a single row
2. Why does the first circle come at last ?

I do not mind if I have to scroll to view all nodes ( may be d3.zoom can help ?)

Looking for pointers. Please find code and data below :

```js
const width = 1413;
const height = 480;

// data

const nodes = [{
    "_time": 1666891307118,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5050",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891307241,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "PROPAGATION_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1110",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891307580,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "PROPAGATION_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1150",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891307937,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5000",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891308121,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5010",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891308278,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "CXML_OUT_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1250",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891308605,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "PROPAGATION_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1145",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891309471,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "CXML_OUT_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1300",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891309485,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "CXML_OUT_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1450",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891313018,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5050",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666902123954,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "EXTERNAL_GATEWAY",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1440",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  }
];

const links = [{
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "time": 123
  },
  {
    "source": 1,
    "target": 2,
    "time": 339
  },
  {
    "source": 2,
    "target": 3,
    "time": 357
  },
  {
    "source": 3,
    "target": 4,
    "time": 184
  },
  {
    "source": 4,
    "target": 5,
    "time": 157
  },
  {
    "source": 5,
    "target": 6,
    "time": 327
  },
  {
    "source": 6,
    "target": 7,
    "time": 866
  },
  {
    "source": 7,
    "target": 8,
    "time": 14
  },
  {
    "source": 8,
    "target": 9,
    "time": 3533
  },
  {
    "source": 9,
    "target": 10,
    "time": 10810936
  }
];
const circleRadius = 25;
const linkColor = '#999'; //#FFFF00
const dangerColor = '#FF5286';
const dangerTimeInSec = 2;
const WAITING_FOR_CONFIRMATION_COLOR = '#F8D06B';
const IN_PROCESS_COLOR = '#6E9FFF';
const COMPLETED_COLOR = '#6CCF8E';
const ERROR_COLOR = '#FF5286';

function getStatusColor(data) {
  if (data.TRACKING_STATUS === 'WAITING_FOR_CONFIRMATION') {
    return WAITING_FOR_CONFIRMATION_COLOR;
  }
  if (data.TRACKING_STATUS === 'IN_PROCESS') {
    return IN_PROCESS_COLOR;
  }
  if (data.TRACKING_STATUS === 'COMPLETED') {
    return COMPLETED_COLOR;
  }

  if (data.TRACKING_STATUS === 'FAILED') {
    return ERROR_COLOR;
  }
  return 'gray';
}

function getTimeTextColor(data) {
  if (data.time > (dangerTimeInSec * 1000)) {
    return dangerColor;
  }
  return linkColor
}

function getTimeBetweenNodes(data) {
  const timeInSecs = data.time / 1000;
  return `${timeInSecs}s`
}

function createChart() {

  const svgId = "svgId";
  const node = document.getElementById(svgId);
  // svg.append('g';)
  while (node && node.firstChild) {
    node && node.firstChild.remove();
  }

  const svg = d3.select(`#${CSS.escape(svgId)}`);
  // const centerX = width /2;
  const centerY = height / 2;
  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-600))
    .force(
      "collision",
      d3
      .forceCollide()
      .radius(function(d) {
        return d.radius * 2;
      })
    )
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(50))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(0).strength(0.55))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, centerY))
    .stop();

  for (let i = 0; i < 300; ++i) {
    simulation.tick();
  }



  const arrowId = `arrow-${svgId}`;
  svg.append("svg:defs").append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", arrowId)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr('refX', 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 5)
    .attr("markerHeight", 5)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
    .style("stroke", linkColor)
    .attr("fill", linkColor)
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

  const lines = svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", linkColor)
    .attr('marker-end', (d) => `url(#${arrowId})`)
    .style("stroke-width", 1);



  const circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', (d) => {
      return getStatusColor(d)
    })
    .style("pointer-events", "visible")
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('r', circleRadius)
  // .call(drag)
  // .call(zoom)
  //   .on('click', handleClick);

  // svg.call(zoom);



  const texts = svg.selectAll('text')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('text-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('font-size', '.8rem')
    .attr('fill', '#FFF')
    .style('pointer-events', 'none')
    .text((node) => `${node.CHECKPOINT}`);

  const timeTexts = svg
    .selectAll("timeText")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("text-baseline", "middle")
    .attr("font-size", ".8rem")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr('fill', (d) => getTimeTextColor(d))
    .style('pointer-events', 'none')
    .text((node) => getTimeBetweenNodes(node));

  const sourceTexts = svg.selectAll('sourceTexts')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('foreignObject')
    .attr("width", 80)
    .attr("height", 80);

  sourceTexts.append("xhtml:div")
    .append('p')
    .attr('class', 'source-text')
    .html((d) => {
      return d.SOURCE.split("_").join(" ")
    });

  circles.attr('cx', (d) => d.x)
    .attr('cy', (d) => d.y);

  texts.attr('x', (d) => d.x)
    .attr('y', (d) => d.y + (circleRadius / 8));

  sourceTexts.attr('x', (d) => {
      return d.x - (circleRadius * 1.5);
    })
    .attr('y', (d) => d.y + (circleRadius));

  timeTexts.attr("x", (d) => {
    return d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x) / 2;
  }).attr("y", (d) => {
    return d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y) / 2 - 10;
  });

  lines
    .attr("d", (d) => "M" + (d.source.x + circleRadius) + "," + (d.source.y) + ", " + (d.target.x - (circleRadius + 10)) + "," + (d.target.y))

}

setTimeout(() => {
  createChart()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svgId" width="1413px" height="100vh"></svg>
```

Comment: You may have just picked this example to demonstrate your problem (and if so, disregard the rest of this comment): But if you're only showing a 'chain', don't use a force-directed layout, why not just calculate a scale (the timing links between nodes seem to have length proportional to their value) and layout your nodes/links according to that?

Comment: @mgraham - I just want circles to point to each other, showing a direction of movement and time it took for that movement. Can you help me with an existing example of scale graph ?

Comment: What I'm suggesting wouldn't be a network. Have a look at this --> https://www.d3indepth.com/scales/ - you work out the scale and positions by cumulatively adding up your timing info, put the nodes at the positions and draw links in between. (https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scalelinear has more info but is probably overly detailed from what you seem to want to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned. Your use case is very simple and can be recreated with the use of scales and shapes. I used a linear scale and used the indexes of the nodes as the domain for the scale, as the time intervals between the nodes differ in multiple orders of magnitude.

Each node is contained within a group to simplify relative positioning of the circle, texts and line.

As the number of edges has length of nodes - 1, I used the each function to iterate separately over the node groups and attach an edge only, if the current index is not the last one.

```js
// data

const nodes = [{
    "_time": 1666891307118,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5050",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891307241,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "PROPAGATION_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1110",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891307580,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "PROPAGATION_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1150",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891307937,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5000",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891308121,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5010",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891308278,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "CXML_OUT_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1250",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891308605,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "PROPAGATION_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1145",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891309471,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "CXML_OUT_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1300",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891309485,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "CXML_OUT_DISPATCHER",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1450",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666891313018,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "QUEUE_PROCESSOR",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "5050",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  },
  {
    "_time": 1666902123954,
    "CUSTOMER_NAME": " Customer_1",
    "CUSTOMER": "CID_123",
    "SOURCE": "EXTERNAL_GATEWAY",
    "SUPPLIER_ANID": "SUPP_ID",
    "TRACKING_STATUS": "FAILED",
    "CHECKPOINT": "1440",
    "DOCUMENT_NUMBER": "DOC_NO_123",
    "PAYLOAD_ID": "PID_123"
  }
];

const width = 1600;
const height = 400;

const margin = 100;

const data = nodes.map((d) => {
d.id = d._time - nodes[0]._time;
return d;
});

console.log({data})

const svg = d3.select('svg');




const container = svg.append('g')
.style('transform', `translate(${margin}px, ${height / 2}px)`);
const innerWidth = width - (margin * 2);

const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, innerWidth])
.domain(d3.extent(data, (d, i) => i));

const groups = container.selectAll('g')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.style('transform', (d, i) => `translate(${scale(i)}px, 0`);


groups.each(function(d, i) {
    const e = d3.select(this);
  if (i < data.length - 1) {
    e.append('line')
      .attr('x1', 0)
      .attr('y1', 0)
      .attr('x2', scale(1))
      .attr('y2', 0);
      
    e.append('text')
        .attr('x', scale(1) / 2)
      .attr('y', -20)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .text(data[i+1].id)
  }
});

groups.append('circle')
.attr('r', 30);

groups.append('text')
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', 5)
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.text((d) => d.id);

groups.append('text')
.attr('x', 0)
.attr('y', 50)
.attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
.attr('font-size', 10)
.text((d) => d.SOURCE);
```

```css
circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: red;
}

line {
  stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg width=1600 height=480></svg>
```

Comment: @Rahul Bhardwaj please consider my answer as the possible solution as it fulfills the specified requirements in your question.

Comment: How do I give you bounty ? Sorry, I have been away and could not validate the answer in time.

Comment: Thanks for giving an upvote and accepting my answer. Unfortunately the bounty has already expired.